# Animating a View

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, objectanimator

I have a `RecyclerView` with this layout shown below.

When I use `view.animate().translateYBy(integer)`, the `View` is translated by the integer specified.

However, if the content in the `RecyclerView` is greater than what is shown on screen I can't scroll down to see the last element. I figured out that the view is trespassing the borders.

How can I make the `View` limit its bottom to the screen borders?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ConstraintLayout but I guess you should not translate the View but instead change its height by modifying the top constraint

Comment: @0X0nosugar how can I animate to slide down if I change the constraints?

Comment: I think a Transition ([ChangeBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/ChangeBounds.html)) should work, see for example this [blog post on transitions](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html) by Alex J. Lockwood

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer is correct or not, But my suggestion is to mention the exact height and width of the row_item.xml in your RecyclerView and add this code will help you scrolling of the view and fit the UI as expected.

```
<HorizontalScollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!-- View want to scroll -->
</HorizontalScollView>
```